# modx revo mSearch2 как добавить в &where несколько условий?

Tags: modx

Подскажите как правильно написать условие &where

```
[[!pdoPage?
&element=`mSearch2`
&parents = `14`
&templates = `4`
&minQuery = `1`
&where = `[[!#GET.sale_filter:is=`1`:then=`{"old_price:>=":1}`]]`
&includeTVs = `image,price,old_price,new_good,sku,model,brand,quantity`
&tpl = `SimpleSearchResult`
&tplWrapper = `@INLINE  <div class="sisea-results-list box inline">
                            [[+output]]
                        </div>`
&limit = `[[!#GET.count-search:default=`12`]]`
]]
```

В этом примере если установлена переменная GET[sale_filter] то включается фильтрация.
А как сделать чтобы добавлялись несколько условий? GET[brand],GET[quantity],GET[sale_filter],GET[price],GET[sort] - какие-то могут присутствовать а может и нет

Answer (score 0):

```
&where = `[[!customSnippet]]`
```

Дабы не иметь проблем с синтаксисом параметра where, я бы посоветовал вам написать отдельный сниппет, который анализирует массив GET переменных, строит необходимый JSON массив и передает его в вызов pdoPage

Comment: В итоге сделал сниппет &where = `[[!additionalParammSearch]]`
но видимо синтаксис не верный, вместо больше или равно, он равно в результатах показывает, подскажите синтаксис :>= комбинаций

Comment: <?php

$items_for_json= [];
if( isset($_GET['ff_price']) && is_array($_GET['ff_price']) ){
    $items_for_json[] = '"price:>=":'.(int)$_GET['ff_price']['min'];
}
$ret_param = "{" . implode(',', $items_for_json) . "}";
return $ret_param;

Comment: нашел, там после запятой пробел должен идти